# Нужно ли двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

> Часто путают термины "икс" и "игрек", икс - это одно, а игрек - это другое.

Нужно ли здесь двоеточие?

Comment: Название буквы **игрек**, а не *игрик*.

Comment: Потому и путают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы поставила точку, разделила предложения,если нельзя, то нужно оставить запятую,двоеточие неуместно,потому что причинных отношений здесь нет, нет и пояснительных.

Comment: А разве здесь не подразумевается пояснение? ...то есть икс-это одно,...

Comment: Нет, вторая часть - ответ, противоположный по содержанию.Часто путают термин "икс" и "игрик", НО икс - это одно, а игрик - это другое. Можно было поставить тире, но их и так там 2, третье нежелательно.